# jQuery bind event for two selectors with on() method

Tags: jquery

I have bound `click` event with `on()` method as below:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.selectorA', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

It works well, however I'd like to bind this click event to two selectors:

```
$('#container').on('click', ['.selectorA', '.selectorB'], function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

What does not work. How can I do this without second `on()` call ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the comma separator

```
$('#container').on('click', '.selectorA, .selectorB', function(e){
```

interestingly, for *events* you don't need the comma:

```
$('#container').on('click mouseenter mouseleave', '.a, .b, .c', function(e){
```